# GeoDataFrame into Oracle Database

Tags: python, pandas, oracle, geopandas, shapely

I tried to push my GeoDataFrame with a geometry column into my oracle DB.

with this code

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy import types
from tqdm import tqdm
import cx_Oracle
import pyodbc
import os
import psycopg2




def push_dataframe(df_sql: pd.DataFrame, table_name, if_exists="replace"):


    dict_dtype = {}
    for col in df_sql.columns:
        if pd.api.types.is_string_dtype(df_sql[col]):
            dict_dtype[col] = types.VARCHAR(255)
    oracle_db = sa.create_engine(
        "oracle://USER:PW@ZZ.YY.local/XX"
    )
    connection = oracle_db.connect()
    df_sql.to_sql(
        table_name.lower(),
        connection,
        schema="SCHEMA",
        if_exists=if_exists,
        index=False,
        chunksize=1000,
        dtype=dict_dtype,
    )

    connection.close()
    return
```

but i get this error

```
NotSupportedError: (cx_Oracle.NotSupportedError) Python value of type LineString not supported.
[SQL: INSERT INTO "SCHEMA".TABLE_NAME(x1, x2, geometry) VALUES (:x1, :x2, :geometry)]
[parameters: [{ 'geometry': <shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString object at 0x7f364accc400>}, }, ]]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/tw8g)
```

I tried many solutions but none of them worked, most of them were for postgis databases i think oracle is a bit more difficult to handle.

Comment: I don't have an Oracle database to work with....   you could serialise the geometry column as **WKT** then it's just a varchar2 (a bit bitter that 256 wide)

Comment: Yep and once you have loaded it into oracle as text, it looks like you might be able to convert it back to geometries with `ssp_geometry`. See e.g. [this question](/q/59699858/). You end up having to do this sort of round trip with most database formats - either directly or under the hood within the database’s python api.

Comment: Does the cx_Oracle example [spatial_to_geopandas.py](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/main/samples/spatial_to_geopandas.py) help?